# How to run unstop jar in shell script

Tags: java, shell

I have a jar I am running this on shell script but I want whenever I close my terminal it will work.I tried to find it but didn't get any answer.Please help me to solve the issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: On what OS you want to do this? On Unix like you do `nohup java -jar my.jar &`. For Win take allok here: [link](http://serverfault.com/questions/39451/there-is-any-way-to-run-processes-in-the-background-in-windows-nohup-equivalent)

Answer (score 1):

If this is on linux then, I think you want [`nohup`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup).

Answer (score 0):

If you use bash, see [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8469/closing-a-terminal-without-killing-its-children/8475#8475) to use the bash builtin `disown`.